# How to find dnsserver ip address?

Tags: dns, server, ip, ip-address, lookup

I am trying to lookup the ip address of the dnsserver.

If

```
dig @dnsserver bankOfAllan.co.uk
```

returns

```
;; ANSWER SECTION: bankofallan.co.uk.      3600    IN      A       10.0.0.1
```

and

```
dig @dnsserver badguy.ru
```

returns

```
;; ANSWER SECTION: badguy.ru.              60      IN      A       172.16.200.1
```

how do you find the dnsserver's ip address (@dnsserver)?

Answer (score 1):

Silly me!

```
dig @dnsserver
```

works

Answer (score 0):

Open network sharing center-> change adapter settings-> right click on connection ->status- Details- gives you all the numbering

or cmd and type ipconfig

Comment: Open cmd and type ipconfig

Comment: ipconfig doesn't work, it says: Sorry, command-not-found has crashed! Please file a bug report at:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/command-not-found/+filebug
Please include the following information with the report:

Answer (score -1):

get your path fixed for cmd- to do this-

computer-Right click- properties -Advance sys properties -> Environment Variables->
Path-(Edit)- should look like this -C:\Windows\System32\
And this should do-

Comment: I'm not using windows, I'm using ssh